# Specify port types in s-function blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I'm building my first s-function block from compiled C code. Everything is going fine, except that the s-function block demands that its interface variables are of type `double`, even though the underlying C interface variables are not. The block raises an error if I connect a boolean signal to the input and try to run.

I'm getting the variables in the code by calling `ssGetInputPortSignal` and `ssGetOutputPortSignal`, and casting the void pointers they return into the correct pointer types.

How do I configure the types of an s-function block's parameters in Simulink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ssSetInputPortDataType](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssetinputportdatatype.html?refresh=true).  Needs to be called in the S-Function `mdlInitializeSizes` function.  In your case you'll need something like:

```
ssSetInputPortDataType(S, 0, SS_BOOLEAN);
```

Assuming the input port is the first one and you're not concerned about the return value.

The function for the outputs is [ssSetOutputPortDataType](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssetoutputportdatatype.html), with identical use.